# Populate Editable text boxes on Sharepoint form

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I have a filter list, where I select a specific list-item on the displayed list. There are 8 fields that I need to retrieve and load onto html boxes. The user can edit some of these returned values. I then need to populate the values for the Document Library Form from these text boxes. Question: How do I do this with code? I am new to jquery, so a code sample would be really helpful, including all initialisations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to get the list items and populate the values in the document library form.
There is a code sample below.

```
     <div>  
    <p>  
        <b>List Items</b>  
        <br />  
        <select style="height:400px; width:200px" multiple="multiple" id="selectalllistitems"></select>  
    </p>    
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://testlz.sharepoint.com/sites/wendy2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('clist2')/items",
            type: 'GET',
            headers: {
                                    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        })
    })
    function successHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("successHandler " + "textstatus:" + textStatus + "data: " + data);


var selectallitems = document.getElementById("selectalllistitems");  
if (selectallitems.hasChildNodes())  
{  
    while (selectallitems.childNodes.length >= 1)   
    {  
        selectallitems.removeChild(selectallitems.firstChild);  
    }  
}  
var display = data.d.results;  
for (var i = 0; i < display.length; i++)  
{  
    var selectitems = document.createElement("option");  
    selectitems.value = display[i].Title;  
    selectitems.innerText = display[i].Title;  
    selectallitems.appendChild(selectitems);  
}  

    }

    function errorHandler(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Request failed: ' + xhr.status + '\n' + thrownError + '\n' + xhr.responseText);
    }
</script>
```

More reference:

Working with lists and list items with REST.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest